# I-Robot Create 2 Connectors

Tags: irobot-create

Am I correct in assuming that the I-Robot Create 2 does not have the 25-pin connector like the original version of I-Robot Create has? Thanks much...Rick

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. The Create 2 uses the same iRobot-proprietary 7-pin serial connector as the 500-800 series Roombas (and possibly the 900 series as well - I haven't checked yet).

While there are third-party options for Create 2 cables, I always advocate first-party parts & accessories. iRobot's cable for the Create 2 is $30. I have one, and it is very well built and has the length for your robot to scurry around while you're interfaced with it. You also don't need to worry about messing with USB-to-serial drivers as you do with third-party cables, iRobot's is pretty plug-and-play - even with ROS on Ubuntu.

On a somewhat related tangent:
Current scuttlebutt is that the Create 3 is not too far off from launch, and that it is likely to be based off of the 900 series Roombas (so a much more comprehensive sensor suite, much better battery, and built-in WiFi). But again, this is just rumor at the moment.

Comment: The 900 series does not have that connector.

Comment: Is there a wireless option for the Create 2? On our Create 1s, we used the Bluetooth Adapter Module (BAM): http://www.elementdirect.com/files/10542B.pdf

Comment: Yes, and kind of no? There are the OSMO adapters, which allow you to establish a Bluetooth connection to your robot. They use the 7 pin serial connection on top, but their range is limited and they are cantankerous at best. When I was using them on 700 and 800 series bots, disconnects were common. They are really only good if you just want to capture data because of this. They're also hard to find these days, since it seems like iRobot no longer makes or sells them.

Comment: iRobot has posted directions for building a Bluetooth adapter, here: http://www.irobotweb.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Bluetooth_Serial.pdf?la=en